# Why changes on site arent updating?

Tags: wordpress

My problem is related with my wordpress site. No matter what i change in files it's not updated on site. Even if I rename public_html to public_html_copy site is still working (even in incognite mode). What can i do? I'm not using any cache plugins, so i don't know where is the problem.

I already contacted to hosting, but I'm using Cloudflare, and they can't help me. But i think it's not related with cloudflare, because that problem exist before i use clouflare.

I tried to delete files and reupload, but as I said, even change public_html doesnt do anything. Im confused..

Comment: It could be due to your browser cache. Have you tried clearing your browser cache? What files are you changing ?

Comment: In public_html folder remove the all code of index.php and simple write text in it and hit  the url. Check changes will occur or not.

Comment: I was changing style.css. I deleted index.php and it worked. But i have to delete that and reedit every time i want to change anything?

Answer (score 0):

You say you are using Cloudflare, yet, [Cloudflare is known to be used for caching everything](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172256-How-do-I-cache-static-HTML-). I am sure that your problem is that Cloudflare cached your pages. Try to [purge](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169246-How-do-I-purge-my-cache-) Cloudflare cache.

Comment: I purged,but still it doesnt change anything. When i changed to public_html_copy site stopped working. But if i deleted style.css everything was normal. I deleted index.php and it worked. But i have to delete that and reedit every time i want to change anything? – audiophonic just now   edit

Comment: How did you try it? Did you purge the cache and then make a change or did you make a change and then purged the cache?

Comment: I made change, and adter that i purged.